# RandomAccessFile -HOW TO SKIP STRING BYTE

Tags: java, io, randomaccessfile

i have a project in jave in which i created a binary file and write into it a data of students.
now i want to skip over a string byte which the user insert in but i dont know how to do that without reading it.
how can i know what is the length of byte i need to skeep?
the inserted data is 'int,string,int...'and so on.
 i use RandomAccessFile, the kode is :

```
    if(ranf.readInt()==id)
            {
                found=true;
                ranf.readUTF();
                System.out.println("please enter new grade:");
                new_grade=s.nextInt();
                ranf.write(new_grade);

            }

            else{
                ranf.readUTF();
                ranf.readInt();
                location=ranf.getFilePointer();
            }
```

-the first int value is the id- im reading first the id of student and then if it does not match to the input i want to skip the next one-without reading the next' String ,int'

Comment: If you don't save additional metadata you always must read all characters, or if you string start with ' and you espace this char in string it could work too in cycle Byte reading. Better way will be save some spacial character on start of every line and if match to student then skip. I really don' know how you check this id's, but if you do some expansive operation it will be slow. RandomAccessFile have bad performance and don't use Regual expressions too. I use BufferenInputStream, and read Bytes to byte array. I'm able in less then minute check 6GB file and take only wanted lines

Comment: yes but if it match how can i skip if i dont know the length of the string after the id? i

Comment: if i find a match with the id i need to change the grade wich is the next int after the string .

Comment: Your code already looks to be correct. What's the question?

Comment: if i use objectinputstream after i entered data to a file by dataoutputstream...it would work??

Comment: If you have one record to every line, you can check new line character. Or if you have strict count of fields, you can count that fields by you separator. Every  time you must check (remember in boolean) if you are in String.

Comment: Object Input/Output Stream is lite easier for saving/loading object, but still you must know types by positions. There is some support for skipping block. But i don't see method to do mark that block in output stream